# How to foreach sql result

Tags: sql, foreach

i have the following problem. I have a table like that:

| RollID | ItemCode | Quantity | DocNum | CountRollIDs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | abcde | 5 | 111 | 5 |

at the moment we get 1 line like that above, but we want to have the line repeated CountRollIDs times. So in this case 5 times and want to add a new RollID every time, like 1235 in the second row 1236 in the third row and so on. Is there any way to do that with normal sql?

Comment: Are these in the table?  Or do you want to create the same as above?  `TOP` may be a good place to start?

Comment: Will your starting table always only contain one row?  `RollID` sounds like an identity/auto-increment value from another table; if so, how will you avoid 1235, 1236, etc colliding with other identity values in that table?  Why wouldn't a composite key be suitable instead *(two columns with values `1234,1`, `1234,2`, etc)*?  Is there a maximum number of times you need to repeat the row?  What database is this for?  *(Different databases have different syntax and functionality, so is this MySQL5.x, MySQL8, Oracle, SQL Server, SQLite, PostgreSQL, etc, etc)*

Comment: No there are more then this one line in the table but i filter it with where DocNum = 111. So the result would be this line. But it could happen that there are 2 lines with the same docNum but different itemCode and CountRollIDs so i would need a result that handles this. The RollID is not auto incremented it should result in the first rollID + the CountRollIDs. The database is SQL Server